# How to obtain file name after image download in javascript

Tags: javascript, download, filenames

I have a short code snippet that brings up a "Save As" dialog for saving an image from the current canvas context in a javascript file. How can I 1) determine if the file save was completed by the user or cancelled, and 2) if completed, the file name specified during the save. Here is the code I am using to bring up the "Save As" dialog. (Note: I am using React and myCanvasRef is a reference to the current canvas that holds the image being saved.)

```
function saveImg(e){
    const can = myCanvasRef.current;
    const imgUrl = can.toDataURL("image/png");
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = imgUrl;
    link.setAttribute("download", "*.png");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: 1) and 2) are not possible from a browser context, as the file system can't be read from there.

Comment: Yes, I thought that might be the case. I think I'll need to take an alternate approach. Thanks!